# Typescript - Dynamically extend interface

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am trying to type an existing React Native module with the following props:

```
useComponent1: boolean
useComponent2: boolean
```

With the following implementation

```
render(){
    if(useComponent1){
        return <Component1 {...props}/>
    }

    if(useComponent2){
        return <Component2 {...props}/>
    }
}
```

I have an interface for components 1 & 2, however, I can't extend both as the props are determined by which component is utilised.

Is it possible to dynamically extends an interface?

If not, is there another solution to this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can be intersection/union type:

```
interface Component1Props { .... }
interface Component2Props { .... }
interface WrapperOwnProps {
  useComponent1: boolean
  useComponent2: boolean
}
type WrapperProps = WrapperOwnProps & (Component1Props | Component2Props);
```

Props type can be additionally asserted:

```
class Wrapper extends Component<WrapperProps> {
  render(){
    const { useComponent1, useComponent2, ...props } = this.props;
    if(useComponent1){
      return <Component1 {...props as Component1Props}/>
    }

    if(useComponent2){
      return <Component2 {...props as Component2Props}/>
    }
  }
}
```